# React TypeScript 16.8 How to set state from a form input

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

When the component loads the default state is shown in the name and age inputs which is great but I want to be able to type in the form fields for name and age, at the moment I can't, if I could I expect the values from the name and age inputs to be updated to the state. Likewise when I press the button. Lastly I feel a should be setting a type definition for the state.

I can't understand how to get the values out of the form inputs and save them to state. I dont want to use a placeholder as the value is removed as the user starts to type. Im unsure how to set a type definition for the state.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const State: React.FC = () => {

  type StateTypes = {
    name: string,
    age: number
  }

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    name: 'Bill',
    age: 23,
  });

  const changeState = () => {
    setState({ 
      ...state, 
      name: 'Jim', 
      age: 25,
    })
  }

  return (
    <div className="home-grid">
      <div>
        <p>Name: {state.name}</p>
        <p>Age: {state.age}</p>
        <hr/>
        <input type="text" value={state.name} onChange={changeState} /><br/>
        <input type="number" value={state.age} onChange={changeState}/><br/>
        <button onClick = {changeState}>Update State</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default State;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
const changeState = (e) => {
    const {value, name} = e.target; 
    setState({ 
      ...state, 
      [name]: value
    })
  }
```

For that to work your inputs need to have a `name` prop with the name of the field: `<input name="name" ... />`

Comment: That works perfectly, Should I be setting a type definition for the state?

Comment: If you mean input's type than it's not necessary for the state, but it's needed to render a proper input element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Form_%3Cinput%3E_types

Comment: I edited the above with StateTypes, as im using typeScript I feel I should enforce some types on the state but im not sure

Comment: Not much experience with TypeScript, but from what I saw you don't need to define types on the state. You could probably define them in the `changeState` tho.

Answer (score 1):

You can change state on change of input or you can create refs of component and get values on click of button.
but as per react docs https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate
better you can keep your state as flat as possible by using multiple `useState` because in hooks react is not responsible for any mutation and if you still want to keep nested state then you can use `useReducer` hook.

here i've just done something just let me know any changes required.

```
const State = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [age, setAge] = useState(0);

  const changeName = ({target}) => {
    setName(target.value)
  }

  const changeAge = ({target}) => {
    setAge(target.value)
  }

  const submitForm = () => console.log({name, age})

  return (
    <div className="home-grid">
      <div>
        <p>Name: {name}</p>
        <p>Age: {age}</p>
        <hr/>
        <input type="text" value={name} onChange={changeName} /><br/>
        <input type="number" value={age} onChange={changeAge}/><br/>
        <button onClick = {submitForm}>Update State</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Would the submitForm function call both changeName and changeAge? Any idea on how to set up the functions or state to the the correct types?

Comment: No in that example state will get updated onChange(i.e. typing in input box) later on submit button press whatever you want to do with that state you can do like passing data to backend or something. 
Let me know if you don't want to update state onChange instead you want that on click only i'll give you that example as well.
correct types you mean in typeScript ?